# Overriding an scss file in the bootstrap system

Tags: bootstrap-5, scss-mixins

I've found that the language-selector text is hidden through an scss file called _visually-hidden.scss. I'm on joomla4 with a RSJoomla template. The scss file is in this folder of the website \media\vendor\bootstrap\scss\helpers_visually-hidden.scss
The function is as follows:

```
 //
// Visually hidden
//

.visually-hidden,
.visually-hidden-focusable:not(:focus):not(:focus-within) {
  @include visually-hidden();
}
```

I would like to make this text indicator visible but i'm not succeeding to override this function with normal css.
Of course i could "delelete" the file .scss but who knows what other things are going to change unwanted.
Also with an update on the system including maybe also a Bootstrap update, my changes are overwritten i think.

Is there some simple way to make the override? I'm NOT familiar with the code in scss files.
Would you look at language selector in real, visit my site https://ambert-camping.com/index.php/fr/

Looking forward to your reactions, thanks, Ron

Answer (score 0):

This is the Bootstrap Mixin that's causing this:

```
@mixin visually-hidden() {
  position: absolute !important;
  width: 1px !important;
  height: 1px !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: -1px !important; // Fix for https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/25686
  overflow: hidden !important;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
  white-space: nowrap !important;
  border: 0 !important;
}
```

If you take a stronger selector, like

```
p.visually-hidden, 
p.visually-hidden-focusable:not(:focus):not(:focus-within)
```

And override the three most relevant attributes with

```
width: auto!important;
height: auto!important;
position: static!important;
```

you should be able to make the element visible with CSS styles.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but i don't get exactly what you mean by taking a stronger selector. And also how to attribute it to the language-text selector.

Comment: Be specific with the selector. `p.visually-hidden` is stronger than `.visually-hidden`. `p#language_picker_des_158.visually-hidden` even more so.

Comment: Sorry but still totaly lost:(

Comment: Then I can't help, I'm afraid. I already gave you the complete code you'd need. Have you tried that already?

Comment: The problem is i don't know how to "attach" the code to the selector. The language selector is "provided" through joomla and the template. So where to input the new stonger slector and override the "standard" setting?

Comment: You wrote that you were not able to override the selector with normal css. So does that mean you don't have a custom stylesheet in the first place?